# Can I use SignalR in a C++ CLI layer?

Tags: c#, c++, signalr

We have a C/S project which has both C# and C++ code. And we use CLI to invoke C# methods in C++ code. Now we use SignalR and it works in C# code.

However, when we try to wrap the SignalR API in CLI layer, we found any invokes from C++ side fails.

**My question is:**

Is there some restriction that a C++ CLI project could not use SignalR in it? I know there is a SignalR C++ client, if the answer is yes I will turn to it.

**There is a lot of codes, so I pick some key steps here:**

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI); 
HubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("SICHub"); 
this.RegistryAction(); // We register the notification action here 
connection.Start(); // The exception throw here
```

**The exception is as following:**

A first chance exception of type

> 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>
> {
>
> Connection: close
>
> Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 09:37:42 GMT
>
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> Content-Length: 315
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
>
> }

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman, done, thanks!

Comment: It says the endpoint can't be found. Is the URL correct?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, thanks, the end point is not correct. We fixed it and our code moved forward and then hit another exception saying "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: I guess still something wrong with the endpoint. Try using Wireshark and see what happens over the network.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, thanks, we fixed this issue. The root cause of the first exception is the wrong endpoint; the root cause of the next one is we passed wrong parameter. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@PatrickHofman, thanks, we fixed this issue. The root cause of the first exception is the wrong endpoint; the root cause of the next one is we passed wrong parameter. Thanks for your help!